# How do you keep a specified element from scaling when zoomed ( iPhone )

Tags: javascript, iphone, css

Say, you have an `<img src='test.png />` within your webpage.

The webpage's dimensions are 1024px x 1000px, the `<meta name="viewport">` is set up so that it allows user scaling.

When a user pinches out ( on an iPhone for examples sake ), how do you prevent the `<img src='test.png />` image from being zoomed?  I want it to stay its original size.

Are there any -webkit specific css selectors that you can place use on elements that you specifically do not want to scale?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. in iOS the scaling is done GPU side, has nothing to do with the code on your website.